# Why is sportsipy data not populating?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip

I'm building a system to predict NFL games. I'm using sportsipy for the data and when I make calls to it it appears there is not data.

Here is my code:

```
from sportsipy.nfl.boxscore import Boxscores
week1 = Boxscores(1, 2023)
print(week1.games)
```

and here's the output

```
{'1-2023': []}
```

and the same thing happens if you change the year to previous seasons that have fully completed. According to the documentation the code should print a dictionary of all matchups for the week, but that isn't the case. I don't know if I'm somehow calling the API wrong or if I haven't set it up correctly. I'm not very familiar with python so all I did to install the module is `pip install sportsipy` but there may be additional setup that I may be unaware of.

How to correctly setup the module and how to use it?

Comment: Possibly because there is no data for the specified week. Do you get any data for the example in the docs? `Boxscores(1, 2017)`

Comment: @foxpal No, I get the same result just with a different year